# How to use xhost/xauth to control X11 access from EC2 to cygwinX

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, x11-forwarding

I must be missing something very simple here:

I am connecting to a RedHat 7 Enterprise EC2 instance from my Cygwin/X Windows desktop.  I use `ssh -XYg -i kekfile.pem user@123-amazonaws.com` to connect.  I then `export DISPLAY=:10.0`.

This works fine as long as on the client side I do:  `xhost +`

But that seems a little risky as it will let anything on my network connect to my local X11 server.  How can you use `xhost` or `xauth` (or something else?) to only allow that one ssh session to use my local X11 server?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to set DISPLAY. If ssh is successfully forwarding X, it'll set an appropriate DISPLAY for you. It also shouldn't be necessary to run "xhost +". Why are you finding it necessary to do that?

Comment: That's what I thought.  But if I just `ssh` onto the EC2 host and run an X program I get:  `xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:
xterm: DISPLAY is not set`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realized that I was doing this backwards.  Hopefully this will help any CygwinX user who wants to host an EC2 machine:

1. Before starting the ssh session `export DISPLAY=:0.0`
2. Just use the `-Y` flag with ssh
3. Once you have the ssh tunnel open do not set DISPLAY.  It is automatically set for you.

Then you can set `xhost -` on your CygwinX side and the tunneled in connection still works fine.